# how open xlsx file in excel

Tags: dired

(On MacOS, emacsclient in `-nw` mode )
when point is at a xlsx file in a dired buffer,
how can I open the xlsx file with MS-Excel.

I have Excel installed in the Mac. and the xlsx file extension is associated with excel.

Comment: look at [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20341216/8544157)

Answer (score 1):

In your init file:

- Require built-in library **`dired-x.el`**, which makes option `dired-guess-shell-alist-user` available.
- Customize option **`dired-guess-shell-alist-user`**, to tell Emacs that you want to associate, in Dired at least, MS-Excel with a `*.xlsx` file.
- In Dired, use **`!`** (followed by `RET`) on an xlsx file, to open it with MS Excel.

`C-h v dired-guess-shell-alist-user` says something like this:

> **`dired-guess-shell-alist-user`** is a variable defined in `dired-x.el`.
>
> Its value is `nil`
>
> Documentation:
>
> User-defined alist of rules for suggested commands.
>
> These rules take precedence over the predefined rules in the variable
>   `dired-guess-shell-alist-default` (to which they are prepended).
>
> Each element of this list looks like
>
> ```
> (REGEXP COMMAND...)
> ```
>
> where each `COMMAND` can either be a string or a Lisp expression that evaluates
>   to a string.  If this expression needs to consult the name of the file for
>   which the shell commands are being requested, it can access that file name
>   as the variable `file`.
>   If several `COMMAND`s are given, the first one will be the default
>   and the rest will be added temporarily to the history and can be retrieved
>   with `M-x previous-history-element` (`M-p`) .
>
> The variable `dired-guess-shell-case-fold-search` controls whether
>   `REGEXP` is matched case-sensitively.
>
> You can customize this variable.

Answer (score 1):

On OSX/MacOS, type:   `!` and then the word `open` and then hit `RET`.

Comment: short and sweet

Answer (score 0):

I have the following config (simplified version):

```
(use-package dired
  :ensure nil
  :defer t
  :commands (dired dired-jump dired-jump-other-window)
  :bind (("C-x C-j" . dired-jump)
         ("C-x 4 C-j" . dired-jump-other-window)
         :map dired-mode-map
         ("<C-return>" . haba/dired-open-in-os))
  :config
  (defun haba/dired-open-in-os ()
    "Open file/folder under cursor in OS."
    (interactive)
    (let ((file (ignore-errors (dired-get-file-for-visit))))
      (browse-url (file-truename file)))))
```

And with `<C-return>` I can open all files using OS handlers. XLSX in Excel, DOCX in Word, etc.

I didn't check if it works on OSX though. :)

PS

Emacs 26 has a new binding `W` in dired that might work out of the box. But there is no windows build yet and I can't check it.

PPS

So in Emacs 26.1 you can use `W` to open XLSX files in Excel.